# 18 digits after the decimal point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have a number 0.780000000000000016 (18 digits after decimal point, type 'number')

I need to convert it to string.

If I make 0.780000000000000016.toPrecision(18) it returns "0.780000000000000027"

What to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: The extra 0.000000000000000016 might have been due to floating point rounding errors (as would the change in the number at the end). Do you absolutely need to have it to 18 decimal places, or would rounding it to a precision that showed 0.78 be enough?

Comment: Yes, I need all 18 decimal places

Comment: The number type is not accurate enough for that many digits. You can't have 0.78000...16 as a number, it has to be a string to start with (or a custom object).

Comment: And how to convert it to string then?

Comment: You can't "convert" it because it doesn't have the accuracy if it starts as a number. If you now have `var a = 0.78...16` change it to `var a = "0.78...16"`.

Comment: The closest JavaScript number (IEEE 754 64-bit binary float) to 0.780000000000000016 is 0.7800000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875. The result you got is just as short as your input, and closer to the actual value.